# Php and Mysql Pagination with search

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following pagination script for my project, the script works fine without a search box
but if I search for teachers by department, the pagination breaks on the second page. It just displays all teachers and ignores my search filer.

```
$per_page =30;//records to display per page

$results = $conn->execute($sql_query); //get data

//count the number of records found
$num_records_found = count($results); 
    
if($_GET['page']==""){
    $page="1";
}else{
    $page=$_GET['page'];
}
    

$start    = ($page - 1) * $per_page;

//I'm searching for teachers by department
$search = $_GET['department'];
$sql     = $sql." where department like '%$search_item%' LIMIT $start,$per_page";
$sql = $conn->prepare($sql);
$results $conn->execute();
 //last page of my pagination
 $last_page = ceil($num_records_found/$per_page);

<ul id="pagination">
    <?php
    //Show page links
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $last_page; $i++)
        {?>
        <li id="<?php echo $i;?>"><a href="?page=<?php echo $i;?>"><?php echo $i;?></a></li>
        <?php           
        }
    ?>
</ul>
```

Also, how can I use this code in a function so I can call it on other pages if I want to do pagination on 3 different pages ?. e.g list-instructors.php, list-students.php & list-courses.php

Comment: You need to put the parameter that your search is based on (`department`), into your pagination link URLs as well - so that you have that same value still available afterwards, when the user did _not_ submit your search form, but only clicked on one of those links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to append your $search_item to the href of your links:

```
<li id="<?php echo $i;?>"><a href="?page=<?php echo $i;?>&search_item=$search_item"><?php echo $i;?></a></li>
```

This way your search item will be preserved as a query string on every page.

if you want to move the code to a function create a function:

```
function create_links($last_page){
 for($i = 1; $i < $last_page; $i++){
   //create your links href  
 }
}
```

checkout [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DiNo5ZKzaC0) tutorial for more clarity